# Proper method for using this sort of swing-top when bottling?

Tags: bottling, techniques

First time brewer here... I have swing-tops that affix to used bottles via this sort of band:

[image: Swing-top with metal band]

I am wondering if I am utilizing it correctly or if there is a trick or something for wrapping the band around the neck of the bottle that I am somehow not seeing or understanding... My first attempt resulted in this:

[image: Swing-top affixed to used bottle via metal band]

While the seal seems to be fairly tight, I am skeptical as to whether or not it is going to hold when pressure starts to build up inside once I have bottled the beer with sugar for the final fermentation process.

Thanks in advance for your advice! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I have used these too. While it does look messy, it definitely works.

Since there are holes over three different heights, you could try to put the band a bit lower, so that it is underneath the lower enlargement of the glass.

Otherwise it looks neat. Did you use a pliers? Because the first time I used them, it was a bloody (literally) mess, my fingers were hurt.

Comment: I didn't use pliers - but, I saw the potential for disaster so I was very careful!